# Where can I specify the SSLProtocol directive

Tags: tls, webserver, apache-http-server

I am configuring an apache server. I enabled SSL/TLS. I want to specify the TLS versions that the server should supports. I added the following lines in the site's configurations file:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I need to specify the TLS versions. I found about the following directive: `SSLProtocol` from: [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol). It is not so obvious where shall I specify this directive? in the configuration files? I do not want to mess things up so that's why I need to ask.

Comment: I think you can put it inside your VirtualHost directive. This ServerFault answer seems to imply this also: https://serverfault.com/questions/714814/enable-only-tls-1-2-connection-to-my-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The docs page you linked to** says:

> Context:  server config, virtual host

"Server config" means it's allowed in the outermost scope, i.e. where you have LoadModule and Listen. "Virtual host" means it's allowed inside a `<VirtualHost>` tag.